# Php messaging system like facebook

Tags: mysql, sql, message

I'm implementing a php messaging system like that of Facebook in php and mysqli.
I have the following in the database
[View the database image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tddeL.jpg)

```
    CREATE TABLE `messages` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user1` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `user2` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `text` text NOT NULL,
 `timestamp` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

**Here is the Query**

```
SELECT id, user1, user2, timestamp
FROM messages
WHERE user2 = $myid
GROUP BY user1
ORDER BY id DESC
```

After trying the code,it gave me the result I wanted but it did not order the message by id

I want it to be in such a way that  each user can view his or her messages ordered by the timestamp.
If you have any other ideas I can also use to implement this ,please let me know.
I have been  stuck in this code for months, Please help!

> Here is the Formatted text of the database

```
id | user1 | user2 |  content 

1     1          2       Hello there User2

2     2          1       Hello there User1

3     3          1      Hello there User 2

4     2          1      Hello there

4     1         4      How are u,user 4
```

> Let's  assume I'm user1,I want it to be like

```
------------------
uid:4:(me)How are you User4
----------------------
uid:2:Hello there
--------------------
uid:3:Hello there User1
--------------------
```

Comment: You're not getting the timestamp, so the order by doesn't have much to work with after the group by. Add it to the column list, or order before the group by

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Your GROUP BY is invalid, and will raise an error in newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode.)

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Comment: Group by clause is used for aggregation. I do not see any aggregation here, just sorting. Remove the group by clause completely.